# DELETE duplicate values in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    Registrations AS R1 
    INNER JOIN Registrations AS R2 
        ON R2.UserItemId = R1.UserItemId 
        AND R2.CourseOfferingId = R1.CourseOfferingId 
        AND R2.Id != R1.Id
WHERE
    R2.Id > R1.Id
```

How should I delete the duplicate values ?

Thanks

Comment: This question is incomplete but I'll offer you this: `delete from Registrations where exists (select 1 from Registrations r2 where r2.UserItemId = Registrations.UserItemId and r2.CourseOfferingId = Registrations.CourseOfferingId and r2.Id < Registrations.UserItemId`

Comment: what does select 1 means over here?

Comment: You could use `select *` or any other expression. The point is whether the subquery returns a result--the result doesn't actually matter. If you just run `select 1` you get a single row and column with a value of `1`.

Comment: I am trying the syntax you mentioned above. It does not deletes the duplicate value.

Comment: Well I meant to type `...and r2.Id < Registrations.Id`. Perhaps that's the problem. If not you'll need to make the question more clear.

Comment: Can you please explain what this syntax is doing ?

Comment: The query says this: delete rows where there's another match but with an Id that's lower.

Comment: But the rows are from same table but different column and the duplicate values are found by using Id, right? But why you have used **...where r2.UserItemId = Registrations.UserItemId** ? I mean why you are calling column with table name(Registrations) not variable name(r2) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll take a stab at your problem. This is only a guess, based on the query you provided. A complete question would have described what exactly you mean by a duplicate row.

```
delete from Registrations
where exists (
    select 1
    from Registrations r2
    where   r2.UserItemId = Registrations.UserItemId
        and r2.CourseOfferingId = Registrations.CourseOfferingId
        and r2.Id < Registrations.Id
);
```

Apparently you have multiple rows that have the same `UserItemId` and `CourseOffereningId` but different `Id` values. I'm presuming that you want to keep the one with the lowest `Id` and discard the others.

The subquery in the query takes each row in the table and checks to see if there's another row like it but with a lower Id. If the answer if yes then the row is deleted.

Answer (score 0):

You can try query like this

```
;with cte as (
select *, RowN = row_number() over(partition by useritemid, courseofferingid, id order by id) from Registrations )
delete from cte where Rown > 1
```

Comment: It would likely help the OP if you included references about CTEs...for their sake...